# How do I delete a file in Qt when the file is already in the file system?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I have a problem when I try to delete a file with Qt.
If I delete it with my Qt application in the same run as the file is created there is no issues, if I try to delete it when it already exists before the application has been launched, I receive an "access denied" issue.
Looking to this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString path = "MyPath"; 

    QFile file(path+"/test.txt");

    if (file.open(QFile::ReadWrite)){
        if(!file.setPermissions(QFileDevice::WriteUser | QFileDevice::ReadUser|
                    QFileDevice::ExeUser)){
            std::cout << "Error in permissions" << std::endl;
         }
        file.close();
        if(!QDir().remove(path+"/test.txt"))
            std::cout << "Can't delete" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If I lanch the application, the file is created and then delete without any problem. If I try to access the file in Qt when it has already been created (by the application in a previous run, skipping the remove part of code) the file can't be delete or accessed.
I have tried to set the permissions but nothing has changed

Comment: This is unlikely to be a permissions problem unless you are running your IDE as administrator. Maybe your antivirus is the problem. Maybe your last executable that you executed is still running.

Comment: @drescherjm I checked if any executable was running and I didn't find anything. And even turning down the antivirus didn't help

Comment: I notice the file name you're creating doesn't match the file you're trying to delete; is this by design?

Comment: @mzimmers my mistake when copying the code here, modified only one of the the names. In the original code both are named name.txt

Comment: hmm...I made that change, and your code works for me, so it's not a Qt problem per se. Not sure what to tell you. I did change the path to "."; maybe you could try that.

Comment: @mzimmers thank you, at least I know that the code is correct, but it still doesn't work for me. I tried to change the opening mode to `ReadOnly` and in this case the file can be read, but can't be deleted or modified. Is there an option for Qt  community that doesn't let you change already existing files?

Comment: no, not that I'm aware (and that would really surprise me). I'm 99% sure the problem isn't in Qt. Have you tried various directories?

Comment: I also doubt the problem is with your code or Qt. I think there is some problem in your folders or your OS. You should not need to set any permissions or anything for this to work.

Comment: Finally I was able to solve this problem thank to you. I tried some directory, and I had to choose one outside of my user space, even tho I'm logged. Thank you!